Inner Product with Doubly-Stochastic Matrix
Let $\vec{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ be a real, normalized vector ($\sum_i x_i^2 = 1$) with nonnegative entries ($x_i \geq 0$). Additionally, let $D$ be a doubly-stochastic matrix, i.e., all of its entries are nonnegative ($D_{ij} \geq 0$) and the sum of its entries on each row and each column is one ($\sum_i D_{ij} = \sum_j D_{ij} = 1$). For $k \geq 1$, consider the following function:
$$
f(k) = \frac{\sum_{ij} x_i^k D_{ij} x_j^k}{ \sum_i x_i^{2k}}
$$
Note that $f(k) \leq 1$, since $| \! | D\vec{x} | \! | \leq |\!| \vec{x} |\!|$. Note also that we can assume $D$ is symmetric, without loss of generality.
I believe that $f(k)$ is a monotonically decreasing function of $k$; I am looking either for a proof of this fact, or a contradictory example. My intuition comes from the fact that $D$ is guaranteed to have a leading eigenvector $\vec{v} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (1, \ldots , n)$, and the magnitude of the projection of $(x_1^k , \ldots , x_n^{k})$ onto $\vec{v}$ can only decrease as $k$ increases. But perhaps this is not enough; for example, perhaps this magnitude decreases somewhat slowly, while other components corresponding to large (but not leading) eigenvalues increase faster.
I've tried several different approaches, the most promising being differentiating $\log f(k)$, but nothing seems to work conclusively. So, my question is: is $f(k)$ monotonically decreasing with $k$, or not?
